# Load header file on condition and having class object of the class that was in header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have to restrict loading of(using the entire class ) header file to 64 bit windows.To do that i included preprocessor(ifdef). But the class refernece was used in the code. How to handle that reference?

Gun.h

```
#pragma once

class Gun
 {
private:
   int stuff;
public:
 void doStuff();
};
```

Gun.cpp

```
#include "Gun.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void Gun::doStuff()
{
cout << stuff << endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#if defined(_WIN64)
#include "Gun.h"
#endIf
int main()
{
Gun *mygun ; // getting Compilation error here
mygun->doStuff();


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add the same if-def around the declaration and usage of mygun.

Comment: C does not have classes. Please be aware that C and C++ are different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply the same restriction to blend out the calling code:

```
#if defined(_WIN64)
#include "Gun.h"
#endIf
int main()
{
#if defined(_WIN64) // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Gun *mygun ; // getting Compilation error here
mygun->doStuff();
#endIf


return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mygun->doStuff(); #else cout << "On 32 bits, you can use only bow-and-arrows" << endl; #endif`. Be nice, let the users know you application will not provide fireARMs to underage, so they'll need to wait until they grow to an Intel/AMD age. ;)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Well, feel free to edit my answer. I'm just too lazy and tired right now.

Comment: `static_cast<friendly_kidding&>("Good God, no!!! I wouldn't dare edit a categorical and definitive answer")`. Laziness is the father of invention,  nothing wrong with it. Have a nice rest.

Answer (score 0):

If your main() function uses class Gun, you must give it a Gun class. Normally people do something like providing two versions of Gun.h (say Gun32.h and Gun64.h), and use #ifdef...#else...#endif to selectively load one of them.